# Dynamically allocate array in functions

Tags: c++

So, I am new to c++ and I would like to know why the value doesn't get updated in the array. Can anybody please explain where I Did wrong. Would appreciate any commends. when I try to execute it, it always returns 0 as in std::cout<<sum<<std::endl; I try to see and I realize that my array doesn't get updated

```
    #include <iostream>
    int sum_of_even(int* arr, int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] % 2==0)
            {
                sum += arr[i];
                std::cout<<sum<<std::endl;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int numbers[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        std::cout<<sum_of_even(numbers,5)<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of the line `arr = new int[n];`?

Comment: Disregard the vector comment. I had my wires crossed.

Comment: I am currently learning about dynamic array so I found this question and try to do it

Comment: You have an array with values in it in `main`. You pass it to the function and then overwrite the value of that pointer with a new array of uninitialized values. Seems like two different things. Are you trying to add up the even numbers in the array that was passed in, or are you trying to allocate memory in a function that will be visible outside that function?

Comment: I am trying to allocate memory in a function that will be visible outside

Comment: Where do you think that you're updating any of the array's values?

Comment: should it be in the function?

Comment: Why do you want to allocate any memory in this function? It looks like it's supposed to calculate the sum of the even elements of the input array.

Comment: Your code will be easier if you use `std::array`. You can pass this object by reference and use the automatic iterators to loop over it without having to track the length of the array. If you already have flat array you can pass it to the function using `std::span`. Using these types of objects makes your code safer and less prawn to bugs.

Comment: @mansdz Additionally, note that your code is also prone to memory leaks due to `new[]` because you never call `delete[] arr;` after allocating it.

Comment: If you want to allocate memory using `new` inside a function using a passed in parameter you need a reference to a pointer. `void foo(int*& ptr) { ptr = new int[20]; }` There are many reasons this is not the best way to do things. Use a container like a `std::vector` or if you must use a raw pointer just return it. Your example is confusing since it sure looks like you're trying to add up the numbers and the memory allocation is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

When arrays condense into pointers in a function parameter, it stores the *addresses* to the first element in the array. Addresses are just locations in memory, and nothing more, they have nothing to do with their contents, so what this line does:

```cpp
arr = new int[n];
```

This just makes the whole *passing the pointer to the first element of the array* useless since the first thing you do with the pointer is make it point to a different memory that was allocated using `new[]` that is completely unrelated to the array you pass to the function.

Additionally, `new[]` will not *magically* initialize all your elements, so what you see are *uninitialized/undefined values* inside the dynamically allocated memory, and trying to read uninitialized values is *Undefined Behavior* in C++ because you can get any sort of value out of it.

So you *have* to initialize the memory manually after allocating it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int sum_of_even(int* arr, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int* const tmp = arr; // Store the pointer to the first element of the array temporarily as the line below will immediately replace it
    arr = new int[n];
    std::copy(tmp, tmp + n, arr); // Initialize the dynamically allocated memory with values inside 'arr'
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
            std::cout << sum << std::endl;
        }
    }
    delete[] arr; // You NEED to call `delete[]` after using `new[]` or say hello to memory leaks!
    return sum;
}

// ...
```

Or just get rid of the dynamic allocation entirely since it is not needed and adds needless overhead.

**Edit:** It appears that you are trying to allocate at the address where the array is situated. You can do that using [placement new](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/placement-new.html):

```cpp
arr = new (arr) new int[n];
```

But this is kind of useless and isn't really needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `sum_of_even()` you provide the address of the first element of `numbers` as the parameter `arr`.

But then in `sum_of_even()` you replace this address with the result of `new int[n]`.

So you don't sum up the values of `numbers`.

Comment: Tl:DR  remove `arr = new int[n];` ;-)

Comment: :-D OP asked "_why_".

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the address of the array, not the array itself. You can see this if you add a debug statement printing the value of arr immediately inside sum_of_even. You will see something like 0x7fff1c32e890 displayed. This is the machine address where arr is stored.

Change sum_of_even to receive an array, not a pointer:

```
int sum_of_even(int arr[], int n)
```

and as previously mentioned, this line wipes out your entire array

```
arr = new int[n]
```

Comment: "Change sum_of_even to receive an array, not a pointer:"  that's actually the same thing.  And it's not recommended, since it is in fact transformed into `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-assigning the `int* arr` pointer to point to a different memory address created on the heap with `new int[n]` in this line:

```cpp
arr = new int[n];
```

You can see your code working as expected [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fKhYo3WTa) when commenting out that line, which means you are not accessing the actual `numbers`  array.

It is also good practice to indicate the intention of your function through using `const` when passing parameters. E.g. if you want to safely prevent the re-assigning of the pointer inside your function, thus indicating "read-only", use this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xeccje7Kh):

```cpp
// The order of const and the type int* matters here
int sum_of_even(int* const arr, int n)

/* Compiler error:
<source>: In function 'int sum_of_even(int*, int)':
<source>:5:13: error: assignment of read-only parameter 'arr'
         arr = new int[n]; */
```

As an added note. Your function creates a memory leak, due to not freeing the `new int[n]` array. This is done through adding `delete [] arr;`

I would also propose to solve your problem in a *modern cpp* way through using the containers and `std` functions available in the [stl](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

For example, rather add your numbers to a `std::vector` container and use `std::accumulate` in combination with a lambda to sum your even numbers as in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/T4r4Gefjr):

```cpp
// Use a vector container for your data
std::vector<int> numbers{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// Create the sum with a combination of accumulate and a sum if even lambda
int sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), 
                          numbers.end(),
                          0,  // Start with a sum of zero
                          [](int sum, int num) {
                           // Sum only on EVEN numbers
                           return num % 2 == 0 ? sum + num : sum;
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the array again in your function due to which the array you passed is not even being used in your function.
An uninitialized array is being used in your function making your sum carry wrong value